# How to change users while preserving the store?

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I want to implement a "fast login".

I'm developing an enterprise software where a lot of users work in the same organization with the same data in the same computer and I want to be able to know who did what and when. Right now they have to log out and log in and load the data has to be loaded into the store all over again.

What I want is for them to be able to, without logging out, click on a user, from the organization, insert his password and the user is switched while preserving the store.

Any idea how I can accomplish this?

I'm using `ember-simple-auth v1.1.0` and `ember v2.10.2`

Comment: I've never heard of this. Are you worried about a user forgetting to switch users before doing work?

Comment: I just want a user to be able to quickly login as himself on a computer that a coworker was using and not have to wait for the data to be loaded again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to solve it by simply using `authenticate()` with another user but never calling `invalidateSession()` which is the function that calls `sessionInvalidated()` that looks like this:

```
sessionInvalidated() {
    if (!testing) {
      if (this.get('_isFastBoot')) {
        this.transitionTo(Configuration.baseURL);
      } else {
        window.location.replace(Configuration.baseURL);
      }
    }
  }
```

So by not calling `sessionInvalidated()` the user isn't redirected or the page refreshed and the new user is able to keep using the store without switching pages.

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest solution would be disabling page reload when user logs out. As far as I know, it's a reload causes data loss from store, not a logging out by itself. To do this, you need to overwrite `sessionInvalidated` method in your `application` route. For example,

```
sessionInvalidated() {
    this.transitionTo('/login');
},
```

But remember - you lower security with this method: if someone will log out and leave webpage with app open, other person will have a possibility to extract data (if they have enough technical background to at least install ember inspector).

Other solution will require heavy research. I think it should be possible to implement custom authenticator which would allow to authenticate new user without logging out previous, by simply replacing tokens in store. But I don't know how hard it will be to implement and what obstacles you can meet. You will need to read ember-simple-auth's sources a lot, that's for sure.